# Which branches should be associated with deployment slots in Azure

Tags: git, azure, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree, continuous-deployment

I'm launching an application on Microsoft Azure using deployment slots and source control. I'm in doubt which branch to associate with production deployment slot. If I setup a staging environment and connect that to master branch and then run a swap, it correctly switches to the master code base in production slot. If I swap back it swaps to staging, it shows old code in production. This tells me that production is currently not associated with a branch (which I also didn't set it up to be).

My question is now, which branch do I associate with staging and which branch do I associate with production?
When and how will the code in production be replaced so that I can put new code in staging (master branch)?

My concerns are:
- If there is no branch associated with production, then how can I switch correctly between deployment slots and get value of the feature?
- If I associate a branch with production slot, then that code won't go through staging environment when deployed.
- I assume that I want to not switch source control repository branch on my online environment every time I want to deploy.
- If I set it up like this then I would think that I have to deploy to staging environment and then swap to production. In order to have that codebase in production I would have to deploy that same code to production afterwards.
- I thought I would always merge a branch into master and not into another branch first.

I believe there is something I'm not getting right. What do I have to do?
Please explain in relation to what code to have in master branch.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There should not be separate branches associated with the production and staging slots, or at least there is no benefit I can think of to doing so. The staging slot exists as an intermediate step in getting your code into the live production environment, allowing you to have the VMs deployed, running and scaled before they are switched into the customer facing production slot.

If you have different versions of your code you want to have deployed to Azure then create a separate Cloud Service for each one, so each code branch is associated with its own cloud service. You do not have to use the staging slot for every deployment, for example a Dev branch/Dev cloud service may not require going through the process of deploying to staging and then performing a VIP swap, in that case you can just upgrade the production slot in-place.

In this scenario your issue with the staging slot containing different code should be restricted to it containing only the previous deployment of the same branch. After a deployment and your new production code is live in the production slot you have a choice of deleting the contents of the staging slot, or keeping it in place so that you are able to roll-back to the previous version in the time it takes to do a VIP swap.

There is also no hard and fast rule, so it's about finding the process that works best for you.

Comment: I was looking into this to setup the same type of environment for R&D. The main benefit of having different branches for different environment is the ability to do hot fixes easily and also have a cleaner master branch (if you use this one for production) with potentially only commit/tags for releases.